# Uploading images using form ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, file-transfer

I have a website that has a form and users can upload one image before submitting the form.

I am trying to do the same thing with Ionic framework.

**What I have done so far:**

Installed ngCordova [Steps](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/)

Added plugins:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

And here is my run:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova'])

    .run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            console.log(FileTransfer);
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
        });
    })
```

Console prints out:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined

I'm stuck here, I tried an example controller but it did not work. I am using *ionic serve -l* to test this, and *ionic View* on my iPhone. Anyone has any idea why or how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I tried on android mobile phone and worked for me. First I created a starter ionic app and follow the all steps you mentioned then I did `cordova prepare` and it worked for me.

Comment: @pradeep1991singh Hey, thanks for helping! Did you try on emulator or on a device? I haven't used `cordova prepare` I will try it out asap. thanks again!

Comment: on device, so you are testing on device right? because plugin wont work on emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps are correct, just test in emulator or real device rather than web browsers, because web browser is not support cordova plugins that depend on native platforms.